# Trouble using hashq-get-handle in Guile

Tags: json, emacs, scheme, hashtable, guile

I'm having trouble getting the value associated with a key in a hash-table and I'm totally confused as to what I'm doing wrong.  The code I'm using is shown below:

```
(use-modules (curl))
(use-modules (json))

;; use curl to hit the site's api to get results of query as json:                                                                   
(define handle (curl-easy-init))
(curl-easy-setopt handle 'url
              "http://api.data.gov:80/regulations/v3/documents.json?api_key=mySecKey&countsOnly=0&encoded=1&dktid=EPA-HQ-OAR-2013-0602&dkt=R&cp=C&rpp=25&po=0")
(define s (curl-easy-perform handle))

;; parse the json in the string into guile scheme:                                                                                   
(define queryResults (json-string->scm s))

;; use this to see the keys and values in the resulting hash table:                                                                  
(define print-hash (lambda (my-hash)
                     (hash-for-each (lambda (key value)
                                      (format #t "~a => ~a~%" key value))
                                    my-hash)))

;; now let's take a look at the keys and values:                                                                                     
(print-hash queryResults)

;; now let's get the value associated with the documents key:                                                                        
(hashq-get-handle queryResults 'documents)
```

It relies on [guile-curl](http://www.lonelycactus.com/guile-curl.html) and [guile-json](https://github.com/aconchillo/guile-json) to talk to the webserver and to parse the response.  Things seem pretty straight-forward until I run.  I can see the response from the server in json (very long and not posted here) and from within Emacs (using geiser to poke around) I can see:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (hash-table? queryResults)
$25 = #t
```

so I know that queryResults is indeed a hash-table.  When I take a look at the keys and associated values using print-hash I see that:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (print-hash queryResults)
totalNumRecords => 23318
documents => (#<hash-table 2ad7c60 17/31> #<hash-table 2afdbc0 17/31> #<hash-table 2b0ab60 17/31> #<hash-table 2b0eb00 17/31> #<hash-table 2b10aa0 17/31> #<hash-table 2b13a40 17/31> #<hash-table 2b189e0 17/31> #<hash-table 2b1b980 17/31> #<hash-table 2b1e920 17/31> #<hash-table 2b228c0 17/31> #<hash-table 2b25860 17/31> #<hash-table 2b29800 17/31> #<hash-table 2b2d7a0 17/31> #<hash-table 2b30740 17/31> #<hash-table 2b336e0 17/31> #<hash-table 2b38680 17/31> #<hash-table 2b3b620 17/31> #<hash-table 2b3f5c0 17/31> #<hash-table 2b44560 17/31> #<hash-table 2b48500 17/31> #<hash-table 2b4c4a0 17/31> #<hash-table 2b50440 17/31> #<hash-table 2b533e0 17/31> #<hash-table 2b57380 17/31> #<hash-table 2b5c320 17/31>)
```

so that's good and it's what I expected.  But when I try to use hashq-get-handle to get a look at the value for totalNumRecords or documents I get:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (hashq-get-handle queryResults 'totalNumRecords)
$24 = #f

scheme@(guile-user)> (hashq-get-handle queryResults 'documents)
$24 = #f
```

which seems to indicate the key doesn't exist in the hash-table queryResults.  I've tried all night with quotes, w/o quotes, futzing with the SRFI-69 hash-table implementations (during which I discovered the difference between native guile hash-tables and the SRFI-69 hash-tables), and went through the [hash table examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Hash-Table-Examples.html#Hash-Table-Examples) in the guile reference manual (they all worked just fine).  I'm out of ideas.

If someone could help me understand why my calls to hashq-get-handle aren't working out as expected I'd be most grateful.

**UPDATE**: Following ttn's suggestion from the guile-user mailing list:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (hash-get-handle queryResults 'totalNumRecords)
$27 = #f
scheme@(guile-user)> (hashv-get-handle queryResults 'totalNumRecords)
$28 = #f
```

So it seems like the result is the same. No love.

Comment: I'm updating with comments from discussion on the guile-user@gnu.org mailing list:  (from ttn): IIUC, the hash table object ‘queryResults’ is made by:

 https://github.com/aconchillo/guile-json/blob/master/json/parser.scm
proc ‘read-object’.  For interop w/ the ‘make-hash-table’ it calls, you might try some variants of ‘hashq-get-handle’, namely ‘hash-get-handle’ or ‘hashv-get-handle’.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/guile-user/2014-12/msg00004.html) discussion on the guile-user mailing list (from both Thien-Thi Nguyen and Mark H Weaver) yielded the solution summarized here:

> Based on a quick glance at the json code, I suspect you want this:
>
> (hash-get-handle queryResults "documents")
>
> i.e. change 'hashq-get-handle' to 'hash-get-handle', and pass a string
>   as the key, not a symbol.

Which ends up working out:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (hash-get-handle queryResults "documents")
$29 = ("documents" #<hash-table 297f820 17/31> #<hash-table 2982700
17/31> #<hash-table 29896a0 17/31> #<hash-table 298f640 17/31> #\
<hash-table 29915e0 17/31> #<hash-table 299d580 17/31> #<hash-table
29a1520 17/31> #<hash-table 29a34c0 17/31> #<hash-table 29a6460 \
17/31> #<hash-table 29f7400 17/31> #<hash-table 29fd3a0 17/31>
#<hash-table 2a08340 17/31> #<hash-table 2a1c2e0 17/31> #<hash-table \
2a4b280 17/31> #<hash-table 2a96220 17/31> #<hash-table 2aa31c0 17/31>
#<hash-table 2aa5160 17/31> #<hash-table 2aaa100 17/31> #<has\
h-table 2ab10a0 17/31> #<hash-table 2abb040 17/31> #<hash-table
2accfe0 17/31> #<hash-table 2acef80 17/31> #<hash-table 2ad1f20 17/3\
1> #<hash-table 2af1ec0 17/31> #<hash-table 2af4e60 17/31>)
```

And a futher suggestion Mark made that makes good sense:

> If you use "~s" instead of "~a" in 'print-hash', it will be clear
>   whether the keys are strings or symbols because strings will print
>   within double quotes.